# Mysql - when increase 'max_connections', what other paramters to adjust accordingly?

Tags: mysql, max-connections

I know some `memory` / `cache` / `open file` related params  should be adjusted accordingly.

But after searching for quite a while, didn't found a comprehensive guide.

Say, `mysql` **8** is in use, running on `Linux`, and trying to change `max_connections` to **400**, the database is using `innodb` engine, could you give a list of other parameters, and their new values to adjust to, in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main setting is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  It should be set to about 70% of available RAM if you have more than 4GB of RAM.

If you need more than the default 151 for `max_connections` it is worth looking into whether the client(s) are allowing too many connections.  It is better to reduce the load from that size.

A common problem is `open_files_limit`.  It comes from the OS's `ulimit` may be at a painfully low 1024.  That should be fixed in the OS.

There are no other "likely" settings to check on, especially with MySQL 8.0.

There are `STATUS` values that can help tuning busy systems.  See this for guidance in that help:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning